# Updated monero-wallet-gui (mac os) and now it won't sync

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

```
2022-08-17 06:44:51.427 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2022-08-17 06:44:53.530 W Failed to get top block hash to check for new block's parent: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2022-08-17 06:44:53.531 E Error adding block with hash: <ee1b15204affc220ac687fb9e879bfdfd0bcdc612b0523f958423cced76fefce> to blockchain, what = Failed to get top block hash to check for new block's parent: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2022-08-17 06:45:10.262 I [212.186.18.77:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1236532 -> 2691382 [Your node is 1454850 blocks (5.5 years) behind] 
2022-08-17 06:45:10.262 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2022-08-17 06:45:11.283 E Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2022-08-17 06:45:11.283 E Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2022-08-17 06:45:11.283 E Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2022-08-17 06:45:11.283 E Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2022-08-17 06:45:11.283 E Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2022-08-17 06:45:11.283 W DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found
2022-08-17 06:45:11.283 E Exception at [add_new_block], what=DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found
2022-08-17 06:45:11.284 W Failed to commit a transaction to the db: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2022-08-17 06:45:11.284 E Exception in cleanup_handle_incoming_blocks: Failed to commit a transaction to the db: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
```

Comment: Please see the guide I linked. Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: thanks, i'm on mac os and can\t find data.mdb. i've tried showing hidden files but nothing

Comment: `data.mdb` is located in `.bitmonero/lmdb`. You can use `COMMAND + SHIFT + .` to show hidden files in Finder. See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402026